# Casual trick taking penalties for illegal plays

Tags: house-rules

I want to know if there is any standard penalty for when someone breaks a rule in a trick taking game, especially failing to follow suit when required.  I know the penalty would depend on the game, but all I could find is this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revoke), which suggested some rather harsh penalties, especially for new players.

I'm looking for more lax penalties for less experienced players, especially for Spades and Hearts.  The best I've come up with is trying to reverse play when possible, but that doesn't always work, especially when the error is discovered many tricks later.

Comment: The penalties are harsh because **there is no excuse for such errors to be made, even by a beginner, more often than once or twice a decade of frequent playing.** The only way to make this point forcefully is with harsh penalties - lax penalties will simply encourage your newbies to cheat with the penalty.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I disagree. I believe the penalties are harsh because (1) they can be difficult to verify (someone has to pay close attention for plays that invalidate past plays), and (2) they are often difficult, if not impossible to fix.

Comment: The reason for the harsh penalty is because this type of mistake is impossible to fix after the fact and very easy to avoid by paying attention. There is not much difficulty in following the suit that was lead

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I think you have a very different definition of "casual" than the rest of us, to the point of coming off as a little insensitive. We're talking about people who may not play a lot of games, likely chatting and not 100% focused on the game. I've seen very bright people who *do* know the game make mistakes when they're not focused (and not because they're trying to cheat); it's surely going to happen with beginners in casual games. Maybe the harsh penalties are still a good idea, but it's not because no one's ever going to make a mistake.

Comment: @Jefromi: I can, and have, played kitchen bridge over a few beers with players more casual than myself. However, all penalties were and are always applied by the book because we realized that that was the only way to be fair to non-cheaters. In my books, anyone who claims the rules should not apply to their mistakes *because the game is casual* immediately comes across as trying to enable cheating, because that is exactly the way an actual cheater would argue. If one would not be thought a cheater, don't sound and act like one. If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, maybe it's a duck.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens In other words, you're saying the penalties should be harsh because otherwise some people might cheat, which is *completely* different from saying that there's no excuse for the errors and that people will make them once or twice a decade. The point about cheaters is still valid (at least in some circles); you just don't have to be so harsh on the people who make legitimate mistakes to make it.

Comment: @Jefromi: In bridge at least, the penalties are the determination of a skilled and learned committee as the best balance in both preventing the deliberate misplay to enable cheating, while still enabling a result to be obtained on the hand and attempt to redress damage appropriately. Where one is available, an impartial arbitrator is enabled to prevent excess in either direction. As a skilled and successful tournament bridge player for over 4 decades now, my answer to any question such as this will always be coloured by the absolute intolerance for unethical behaviour in bridge tourneys.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The OP is asking about spades and hearts, and if bridge tournaments have something to do with your answer, I stand by my point about you thinking of casual play very differently from the OP.

Comment: How is following suit a hard rule to learn and follow?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been online to clarify, but notice my house-rule tag.  Casual does NOT mean tournament-level arbitration.  I'm looking for compromise for new players.  As they get more experience, I would graduate them into more standard penalties.  I'm trying to avoid alienating people just because they are new to the quirks of a different game.

Comment: Casual also doesn't mean that simple and basic rules can be ignored, and knowing to follow suit is about as basic as you can get as it is a rule in almost every trick based card game.

Answer (score 3):

Generally when I play games like that and a miss play is caught before the next trick is played then the play is corrected.  However if it is caught later then the player that messed up losses the hand. In hearts for example they would take all 26 points and everyone else would get 0. In a game where you want points they take the penalty for not getting the minimum bid or whatever they bid. This seems to be a quick and fair way to handle miss plays that you can't correct.

It may sound harsh but following suit in a card game should be a very simple strategy.

Only other option is to throw out the hand and redo it.