# Is there a penalty for forgetting to draw?

Tags: canasta

In a 2 player game, if a player forgets to draw from the stock and tables their first meld (without needing to draw the top discard), would there be a penalty? Or, once noticed could they then draw from the stock?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44334/putting-opponent-s-cards-in-your-hand-in-canasta